# In Gutenberg, now that withAPIData is being deprecated, how can I do an async call to a custom endpoint?

Tags: endpoints, block-editor

I have this working in my plugin and all is well with the world:

```
edit: withAPIData( props => {
            return {
                roles: '/matt-watson/secure-blocks/v1/user-roles/'
            };
        } )( props => {
```

....

However guidance here suggests that this will no longer be supported going forward: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/7390#issuecomment-398667802

So I have managed to work that into the solution:

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
userRoles: {},
};

const actions = {
    setUserRoles( userRoles ) {
        return {
            type: 'SET_USER_ROLES',
            userRoles,
        };
    },

    fetchFromAPI( path ) {
        return {
            type: 'FETCH_FROM_API',
            path,
        };
    },
};

registerStore( 'matt-watson/secure-block', {
    reducer( state = DEFAULT_STATE, action ) {

        switch ( action.type ) {
            case 'SET_USER_ROLES':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    userRoles: action.userRoles,
                };
        }

        return state;
    },

    actions,

    selectors: {
        getUserRoles( state ) {
            const { userRoles } = state;
            return userRoles;
        },
    },

    controls: {
        FETCH_FROM_API( action ) {
            return apiFetch( { path: action.path } );
        },
    },

    resolvers: {
        * getUserRoles( state ) {
            const path = '/matt-watson/secure-blocks/v1/user-roles/';
            const userRoles = yield actions.fetchFromAPI( path );
            return actions.setUserRoles( userRoles );
        },
    }

    ,
    } );
```

....

```
edit: withSelect( ( select ) => {
                                return {
                                    roles: select('matt-watson/secure-block').getUserRoles(),
                                };
                            } )( props => {
```

....

Now the issue is that the 'controls' section never fires. In the documentation it says that this is an opt-in component, and I need to enable it via the `use` command: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/data#controls

When I try this, `use` is undefined.

So my question is this. As `withAPIData` did everything I needed in a very quick and easy way, is there an alternative 'drop-in' bit of code I can use, or do I need to progress with the store that I am registering? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would note that `...` is also valid javascript, as the object spread operator

Comment: I would also guess that you need to define some packages as requirements via npm for the parts that require `use`

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, yeah good point on the `...` I'll have to come up with another way to add snippets. 

I'll have another look into `use`. If I fix this I'll write a glorious blog post!

Comment: Hmm, no luck importing @wordpress/data, I can get the use functions, but not a lot happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's worth noting that the answer above is out of date. The data store should now look like this:

```
const actions = {
    setUserRoles( userRoles ) {
        return {
            type: 'SET_USER_ROLES',
            userRoles,
        };
    },
    receiveUserRoles( path ) {
        return {
            type: 'RECEIVE_USER_ROLES',
            path,
        };
    },
};

const store = registerStore( 'matt-watson/secure-block', {
    reducer( state = { userRoles: {} }, action ) {

        switch ( action.type ) {
            case 'SET_USER_ROLES':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    userRoles: action.userRoles,
                };
        }

        return state;
    },

    actions,

    selectors: {
        receiveUserRoles( state ) {
            const { userRoles } = state;
            return userRoles;
        },
    },

    controls: {
        RECEIVE_USER_ROLES( action ) {
            return apiFetch( { path: action.path } );
        },
    },

    resolvers: {
        * receiveUserRoles( state ) {
            const userRoles = yield actions.receiveUserRoles( '/matt-watson/secure-blocks/v1/user-roles/' );
            return actions.setUserRoles( userRoles );
        },
    },
} );
```

I've updated my tutorial: https://mwatson.co.uk/working-with-gutenberg-and-the-wordpress-rest-api/

Comment: Thank you! But you could have edited your answer instead of writing a new one.

Comment: it lacks state updates (requesting, resolved, failed)

Answer (score 4):

I've cracked it!

```
const actions = {
    setUserRoles( userRoles ) {
        return {
            type: 'SET_USER_ROLES',
            userRoles,
        };
    },

    receiveUserRoles( path ) {
        return {
            type: 'RECEIVE_USER_ROLES',
            path,
        };
    },
};

const store = registerStore( 'matt-watson/secure-block', {
    reducer( state = { userRoles: {} }, action ) {

        switch ( action.type ) {
            case 'SET_USER_ROLES':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    userRoles: action.userRoles,
                };
            case 'RECEIVE_USER_ROLES':
                return action.userRoles;
        }

        return state;
    },

    actions,

    selectors: {
        receiveUserRoles( state ) {
            const { userRoles } = state;
            return userRoles;
        },
    },

    resolvers: {
        * receiveUserRoles( state ) {
            const userRoles = apiFetch( { path: '/matt-watson/secure-blocks/v1/user-roles/' } )
                .then( userRoles => {
                    return actions.setUserRoles( userRoles );
                } )
            yield userRoles;
        },
    },

} );
```

This sets the state of the userRoles and returns the userRoles once resolved.

You can then access this like so:

....

```
edit: withSelect( ( select ) => {
                return {
                    roles: select('matt-watson/secure-block').receiveUserRoles(),
                };
            } )( props => {
```

....

Comment: For those interested I have blogged about my solution with context and more detail: https://mwatson.co.uk/working-with-gutenberg-and-the-wordpress-rest-api/